# How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame

Tags: emacs

I am looking for some ideas, please, regarding how to intercept a file before it opens and make a decision which frame to open it in.

I have a modified version of `frame-bufs` by Alp Aker -- https://github.com/alpaker/Frame-Bufs -- that is working with a current version of Emacs Trunk.  I wrote a function that associates the file being opened with the frame that has focus.  I'd like to take it one step further and set up a list of `file types` and `buffer names` that will always be associated with a particular frame.  I was thinking about a function that does something like this:

```
* If the file being opened is
     (or (eq major-mode 'text-mode) (eq major-mode 'latex-mode) )
          (switch-to-frame "TEXT")

* If the buffer being opened is
     (or (equal (buffer-name) "Folder") (equal (buffer-name) "Summary") )
          (switch-to-frame "WANDERLUST")

* After completing either of the above, open the file / buffer.

* Run the custom frame association function -- (associate-current-buffer)
```

I assume that it is possible to figure out what mode a file is before it is actually opened in a frame.  What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: The good news is that this is exactly what `display-buffer-alist` is for. The bad news is that `display-buffer-alist` is pretty complicated to use. Its documentation, and that of `display-buffer`, are complete but quite terse.

Comment: Thank you for the tip -- I'll take a closer look at the documentation for `display-buffer-alist` -- perhaps it won't be too bad since I don't need to take over any existing windows or split any windows, and there will not be any modifications to the existing frame.  I'll have one function that just checks for the frame existence and creates it if there is none by that name.  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html

Comment: `I assume that it is possible to figure out what mode a file is before it is actually opened in a frame.` I think the only way is manually parsing auto-mode-alist and checking against the filename.

Comment: @ Bruce Connor:  Thank you for the thoughts about parsing the auto-mode-alist and checking it against the filename.  I put that idea on my to-do list and I will research it once I get the overall functionality of display-buffer working.  In the meantime, a simple solution appears to be using `string-match . . .` for the common files names and buffer names that I use on a regular basis . . .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```lisp
;;  To try out this example, copy and paste the entire contents of everything
;;  in this answer to the `*scratch*' buffer and type:  M-x eval-buffer RET
;;  Then type:  M-x db-example RET
;;
;;  `db-open-file' also works out-of-the-box by typing:  M-x db-open-file RET
;;
;;
;;  The frame names are defined with the variable `db-frame-name'.
;;  The preconfigured frame names are:  SYSTEM, MAIN, ORG, MISCELLANEOUS.
;;
;;  Buffers are displayed in specific frames based on the `buffer-name'.
;;
;;  If the `buffer-name' matches a regexp defined `db-special-buffer',
;;  then display that buffer in the current frame.
;;
;;  If the `buffer-name' matches a regexp defined by `db-system-buffer',
;;  then display that buffer in a frame named SYSTEM.
;;
;;  If the `buffer-name' matches a regexp defined by `db-main-buffer',
;;  then display that buffer in a frame named MAIN.
;;
;;  If the `buffer-name' matches a regexp defined by `db-org-buffer',
;;  then display that buffer in a frame named ORG.
;;
;;  If the `buffer-name' does not match any of the above-mentioned regexp,
;;  then display that buffer in a frame named MISCELLANEOUS.
;;
;;
;;  The following are a few methods of setting the `display-buffer-alist':
;;
;;  (1) Set the `display-buffer-alist' explicitly with `setq':
;;
;;      (setq display-buffer-alist '((".*" . (db-pop-up-frame))))
;;
;;  (2) Add to an existing `display-buffer-alist' using `add-to-list':
;;
;;      (add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist '(".*" . (db-pop-up-frame)))
;;
;;  (3) Call the function as part of the `display-buffer' statement:
;;
;;      (display-buffer (get-buffer-create "foo") '(db-pop-up-frame))
;;
;;  (4) Use the `display-buffer-alist' on a let-bound basis:
;;
;;      (let ((display-buffer-alist '((".*" . (db-pop-up-frame)))))
;;        [any additional code] )

(defvar db-frame-name "^\\(?:SYSTEM\\|MAIN\\|ORG\\|MISCELLANEOUS\\)$"
  "Frame names that are used to help organize buffers.")

(defvar db-system-buffer '("\\*scratch\\*" "\\*bbdb\\*" "\\*bar\\*")
  "Regexp of file / buffer names displayed in frame `SYSTEM`.")

(defvar db-main-buffer
  '("\\.txt" "\\.tex" "\\.el" "\\.yasnippet" "\\*foo\\*")
  "Regexp of file / buffer names displayed in frame `MAIN`.")

(defvar db-org-buffer
  '("\\*TODO\\*" "\\*Org Agenda\\*" "\\.org_archive" "\\.org")
  "Regexp of file / buffer names displayed in frame  `ORG`.")

(defvar db-special-buffer
  '("\\*special\\*" "\\*baz\\*")
  "Regexp of file / buffer names that will display in current frame.")

(defun db-pop-up-frame (buffer alist)
  (cond
    ;; condition # 1 -- either file-visiting or no-file buffers
    ((db-regexp-match-p db-org-buffer (buffer-name buffer))
      (if (db-get-frame--drew-adams "ORG")
        (select-frame-set-input-focus (db-get-frame--drew-adams "ORG"))
        ;; If unnamed frame exists, then take control of it.
        (catch 'break (dolist (frame (frame-list))
          (if (not (string-match db-frame-name
                (frame-parameter frame 'name)))
            (throw 'break (progn
              (select-frame-set-input-focus
                (db-get-frame--drew-adams (frame-parameter frame 'name)))
              (set-frame-name "ORG"))))))
        ;; If dolist found no unnamed frame, then create / name it.
        (when (not (db-get-frame--drew-adams "ORG"))
          (make-frame (list '(name . "ORG")))) )
      (unless (get-buffer-window buffer)
       (set-window-buffer (get-largest-window) buffer))
      (select-window (get-buffer-window buffer)) )
    ;; condition # 2 -- either file-visiting or no-file buffers
    ((db-regexp-match-p db-main-buffer (buffer-name buffer))
      (if (db-get-frame--drew-adams "MAIN")
        (select-frame-set-input-focus (db-get-frame--drew-adams "MAIN"))
        ;; If unnamed frame exists, then take control of it.
        (catch 'break (dolist (frame (frame-list))
          (if (not (string-match db-frame-name
                (frame-parameter frame 'name)))
            (throw 'break (progn
              (select-frame-set-input-focus
                (db-get-frame--drew-adams (frame-parameter frame 'name)))
              (set-frame-name "MAIN"))))))
        ;; If dolist found no unnamed frame, then create / name it.
        (when (not (db-get-frame--drew-adams "MAIN"))
          (make-frame (list '(name . "MAIN")))) )
      (unless (get-buffer-window buffer)
       (set-window-buffer (get-largest-window) buffer))
      (select-window (get-buffer-window buffer)) )
    ;; condition # 3 -- either file-visiting or no-file buffers
    ((db-regexp-match-p db-system-buffer (buffer-name buffer))
      (if (db-get-frame--drew-adams "SYSTEM")
        (select-frame-set-input-focus (db-get-frame--drew-adams "SYSTEM"))
        ;; If unnamed frame exists, then take control of it.
        (catch 'break (dolist (frame (frame-list))
          (if (not (string-match db-frame-name
                (frame-parameter frame 'name)))
            (throw 'break (progn
              (select-frame-set-input-focus
                (db-get-frame--drew-adams (frame-parameter frame 'name)))
              (set-frame-name "SYSTEM"))))))
        ;; If dolist found no unnamed frame, then create / name it.
        (when (not (db-get-frame--drew-adams "SYSTEM"))
          (make-frame (list '(name . "SYSTEM")))) )
      (unless (get-buffer-window buffer)
       (set-window-buffer (get-largest-window) buffer))
      (select-window (get-buffer-window buffer)) )
    ;; condition # 4
    ;; display buffer in the existing frame
    ((db-regexp-match-p db-special-buffer (buffer-name buffer))
      (unless (get-buffer-window buffer)
       (set-window-buffer (get-largest-window) buffer))
      (select-window (get-buffer-window buffer)) )
    ;; condition # 5
    ;; file-visiting buffers that do NOT match any pre-defined regexp
    ((and (not (db-regexp-match-p db-org-buffer (buffer-name buffer)))
          (not (db-regexp-match-p db-main-buffer (buffer-name buffer)))
          (not (db-regexp-match-p db-system-buffer (buffer-name buffer)))
          (not (db-regexp-match-p db-special-buffer (buffer-name buffer)))
          (buffer-file-name (get-buffer (buffer-name buffer))))
      (if (db-get-frame--drew-adams "MISCELLANEOUS")
        (select-frame-set-input-focus
            (db-get-frame--drew-adams "MISCELLANEOUS"))
        ;; If unnamed frame exists, then take control of it.
        (catch 'break (dolist (frame (frame-list))
          (if (not (string-match db-frame-name
                (frame-parameter frame 'name)))
            (throw 'break (progn
              (select-frame-set-input-focus
                (db-get-frame--drew-adams (frame-parameter frame 'name)))
              (set-frame-name "MISCELLANEOUS"))))))
        ;; If dolist found no unnamed frame, then create / name it.
        (when (not (db-get-frame--drew-adams "MISCELLANEOUS"))
          (make-frame (list '(name . "MISCELLANEOUS")))) )
      (unless (get-buffer-window buffer)
       (set-window-buffer (get-largest-window) buffer))
      (select-window (get-buffer-window buffer)) )
    ;; condition # 6
    ;; default display for no-file-visiting buffers
    (t nil )))

;; https://github.com/kentaro/auto-save-buffers-enhanced
;; `db-regexp-match-p` function modified by @sds on stackoverflow
;; http://stackoverflow.com/a/20343715/2112489
(defun db-regexp-match-p (regexps string)
  (and string
       (catch 'matched
         (let ((inhibit-changing-match-data t))
           (dolist (regexp regexps)
             (when (string-match regexp string)
               (throw 'matched t)))))))

;; Original Author:  Drew Adams -- http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/frame-fns.el
;; @lawlist combined the functions `get-frame-name` and `get-a-frame`.
(defun db-get-frame--drew-adams (frame)
  "Return a frame, if any, named FRAME (a frame or a string).
  If none, return nil.
  If FRAME is a frame, it is returned."
  (let ((get-frame-name--drew-adams
          (lambda (&optional frame)
            (unless frame (setq frame (selected-frame)))
            (if (framep frame)
                (cdr (assq 'name (frame-parameters frame)))
              (error "Argument not a frame: `%s'" frame)))))
    (cond ((framep frame) frame)
          ((stringp frame)
           (catch 'get-a-frame-found
             (dolist (fr (frame-list))
               (when (string= frame (funcall get-frame-name--drew-adams fr))
                 (throw 'get-a-frame-found fr)))
             nil))
          (t
           (error "Arg neither a string nor a frame: `%s'" frame)))))

(defun db-open-file (&optional filename)
"With assistance from the `display-buffer-alist', locate or create a
specific frame, and then open the file."
(interactive)
  (let ((display-buffer-alist '((".*" . (db-pop-up-frame)))))
    (display-buffer (find-file-noselect
      (if filename
        filename
        (if (eq system-type 'darwin)
          (ns-read-file-name "Select File:  " "~/" t nil nil)
          (read-file-name "Select File:  " "~/" nil nil nil nil) ))))))

(when (eq system-type 'darwin)

  (defun db-ns-find-file ()
    "Do a `find-file' with the `ns-input-file' as argument."
  (interactive)
    (let* (
        (display-buffer-alist '((".*" . (db-pop-up-frame))))
        (f (file-truename (expand-file-name (pop ns-input-file)
              command-line-default-directory))) )
      (ns-hide-emacs 'activate)
      (display-buffer (find-file-noselect f))))

  (defalias 'ns-find-file 'db-ns-find-file) )

(defun db-example ()
"This is an example that uses the custom function `db-pop-up-frame' to
display buffers in different frames or windows depending upon the situation.
The `auto-mode-alist' is set to `nil` due to a bug in one of the versions
of `org-mode' where it attempts to recenter a window that is not visible."
(interactive)
  ;; condition # 3 | file-visiting buffer
  (let* (
      (auto-mode-alist nil)
      (display-buffer-alist '((".*" . (db-pop-up-frame)))) )
    (display-buffer (find-file-noselect "*bar*"))
    (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 20)
    (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 80)
    (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 0 0)
    (message "\*bar\* appears in frame name SYSTEM.")
    (sit-for 2)
    ;; condition # 4(a) | no-file-visiting buffer
    (display-buffer (get-buffer-create "*default*"))
    (message "NO-FILE buffer existing frame.")
    (sit-for 2)
    ;; condition # 2(a) | file-visiting buffer
    (display-buffer (find-file-noselect "foo.txt"))
    (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 20)
    (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 80)
    (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 100 100)
    (message "\"foo.txt\" appears in frame name MAIN.")
    (sit-for 2)
    ;; condition # 1 | file-visiting buffer
    (display-buffer (find-file-noselect "doe.org"))
    (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 20)
    (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 80)
    (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 200 200)
    (message "\"doe.org\" appears in frame name ORG.")
    (sit-for 2)
    ;; condition # 4(b) | file-visiting buffer
    (display-buffer (find-file-noselect "*special*"))
    (message "FILE buffer existing frame.")
    (sit-for 2)
    ;; condition # 6 | no-file-visiting buffer default display
    (calendar)
    (message "Default for no-file-visiting-buffers.")
    (sit-for 2)
    ;; condition # 5 | file-visiting buffer with no pre-defined regexp.
    (display-buffer (find-file-noselect "*undefined*"))
    (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 20)
    (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 80)
    (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 300 300)
    (message "\*IS\* buffer-filename.  \*NOT\* defined by any particular regexp.")
    (sit-for 2)
    ;; condition # 2(b) | no-file-visiting buffer
    (display-buffer (get-buffer-create "*foo*"))
    (set-frame-height (selected-frame) 20)
    (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 80)
    (set-frame-position (selected-frame) 400 400)
    (message "\*NOT\* buffer-filename.  \*IS\* defined by db-main-buffer.")
    (sit-for 2)
    (kill-buffer "*foo*")
    (kill-buffer "*bar*")
    (kill-buffer "*default*")
    (kill-buffer "*undefined*")
    (kill-buffer "*Calendar*")
    (kill-buffer "*special*")
    (kill-buffer "foo.txt")
    (kill-buffer "doe.org")
    (make-frame)
    (delete-frame (db-get-frame--drew-adams "SYSTEM"))
    (delete-frame (db-get-frame--drew-adams "MAIN"))
    (delete-frame (db-get-frame--drew-adams "ORG"))
    (delete-frame (db-get-frame--drew-adams "MISCELLANEOUS"))
    (message "THE END.")))
```

Comment: +1. Isn't 8 seconds a lot to `sit-for`? I know you can break it with user input but still..

Comment: I read slowly and had trouble seeing what was happening, even though I am the one who is writing the code.  :)  I'll shave off a few seconds for the speed-readers.  Fixed.  :)