# How to get emacs to run "bk edit" on a file before its opened?

Tags: emacs, elisp

We have to use BitKeeper and which requires running "bk edit" before it is editable. Making the whole repo editable is out of the question as it is too large. Asking for a way to have emacs automatically run "bk edit" on file that is in a repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please present a use case. I'm sure there should be a better way to do it.
If there's not, I'll update my answer.

I imagine that running the hook on *every* file would be annoying as hell.
I can run a command on any file with <kbd>C-x d !</kbd>.

With this code:

```
(require 'dired-x)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x d") 'dired-jump)
```

<kbd>C-x d</kbd> will not only open current directory with `dired`, but
also jump to current file's line. With this <kbd>!</kbd> will run a command
on the file. This command can be auto-completed with <kbd>TAB</kbd> which
is also superior to your current solution.

### UPD1

Now I see that you want to run `bk edit` only on files in the repository.
Here's how you can do it:

```
(defvar bitkeeper-dirs '("/tmp/"))
(defun bitkeeper-p (file)
  (reduce (lambda (a b) (or a (string-match (expand-file-name b) file)))
          bitkeeper-dirs
          :initial-value nil))

(add-hook 'find-file-hook
          (lambda ()
            (let ((file (buffer-file-name)))
              (when (bitkeeper-p file)
                (read-only-mode -1)
                (shell-command (format "cat %s > /tmp/stuff" file))))))
```

1. You should put a list of your Bitkeeper repositories in `bitkeeper-dirs`.
   The current predicate just tests if the file being opened is in one of
   this directories.
2. You could write a better predicate if you want. I can't since I don't
   know how Bitkeeper works. If it were git, I'd probably call `git status`
   and see what it returns.
3. You should replace `"cat %s > /tmp/stuff"` with `"bk edit %s"`.
   The current string is just there for testing purposes.

### UPD2

In answer to

> The best way to test whether a file is in a bk repo
>   is to run "bk root file" a status of 0 means its in a repo.
>   A status of 1 means it is not.

Here's the new predicate. I can't test it since I don't have Bitkeeper.

```
(defun bitkeeper-p (file)
  (string= "0" (shell-command-to-string
                (format "bk root %s") file)))
```

Comment: Actually its because we are using BitKeeper, which annoyingly requires to run "bk edit" on the file before it can be edited. I wanted emacs to automatically run bk edit on the file when its opened, bonus is if emacs runs "bk edit" only on BitKeeper repo files

Comment: Thanks for the info. The question of why you want to do something can be more important
than what you want to do. The title of the question is good, but if you had added the part 
about `bk edit` and removed the code which doesn't work, it'd be perfect.

Comment: Hello abo-abo, this works but happens after emacs marks the buffer as write protected. So in the OS the file is editable, but emacs still believes the file is un-writeable. Perhaps having it do a revert of the file would work?

Comment: BTW. The best way to test whether a file is in a bk repo is to run "bk root file" a status of 0 means its in a repo. A status of 1 means it is not. Unfortunately our clones can be everywhere and change paths all the time, hard-coding them is not practical. For now I am using "/" to match all files

Answer (score 0):

How about something like `find-file-noselect` -- do your stuff, and then `switch-to-buffer` or use `(display-buffer (find-file-noselect  . .)`  Here is a recent thread of mine that is similar to doing stuff before ultimately displaying the file in a buffer:  [How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame)