# Is there a `display-buffer` combination that will essentially `delete-other-windows`?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using a custom `display-buffer-alist` function:  [How to intercept a file before it opens and decide which frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame)  The magic happens under-the-hood with `find-file-noselect` and then when I'm ready to display the buffer, I've been using `(set-window-buffer (selected-window) (buffer-name buffer))` and `(set-buffer (buffer-name buffer))`.  When more than one window exists in the target frame, however, I'm having difficulty taking over the entire frame without expressly calling `delete-other-windows`.

To completely take over an existing frame with `display-buffer` when more than one window already exists in said frame, is there is a `display-buffer` function or combination of settings to accomplish that task without expressly calling `delete-other-windows`?

Alternatively, is there a `select-entire-frame` function that I can use instead of `(set-window-buffer (selected-window) (buffer-name buffer))`?  I would like the buffer to acquire visual focus -- with no other windows in the frame.

Here is a link to the docs on `display-buffer`: 
http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html#Display-Action-Functions

---

**EDIT** (January 1, 2014):  Based upon the apparent lack of another function or specific setting to essentially `delete-other-windows` and wipe the slate clean on an existing frame with *more than one* existing window, here is the revised tail end (to one or more the various conditions) of my `display-buffer-alist` function that is used in conjunction with `(display-buffer (find-file-noselect filename))`

```
 . . . 
 (delete-other-windows)
 (set-window-buffer (selected-window) (buffer-name buffer))
 (set-buffer (buffer-name buffer))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> Alternatively, is there a select-entire-frame function that I can use instead of (set-window-buffer (selected-window) (buffer-name buffer))? I want the buffer to acquire visual focus.

Not sure what you mean, but if I read that correctly I'd say that maybe you are looking for `select-frame-set-input-focus`.

Comment: The frame acquires focus with `select-frame-set-input-focus`, but doesn't wipe the slate clean if there are existing windows.  Perhaps there is no other choice but to call `delete-other-windows` to completely take over an existing frame?

Comment: Still not sure I understand the question. Yes, `s-f-s-i-f` only sets the input focus. If you also want to delete windows then you need to use something like `delete-other-windows`.

Comment: Thank you -- at some point, I should probably send a note to the Emacs team to suggest that they include a `display-buffer` setting that will `delete-other-windows`.

Comment: You might be able to get all of what you want using `display-buffer-alist`.  Unfortunately, I still cannot fathom it. ;-)  Here's hoping someone else will provide you (us) with a better answer.