# How to re-evaluate shell environment and re-evaluate frame-title-format before opening each buffer in emacs

Tags: git, bash, shell, emacs, ubuntu-12.04

I have integrated my git source+repo name into my emacs frame title so I can be sure of what branch/repo I am working on currently.  I do this by setting this information in the bash shell via `PROMPT_COMMAND` and then getting the information at emacs startup in `init.el` (or `.emacs`) via the `getenv` command for setting the variable `frame-title-format`.

Here's what I do in `~/.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="export GIT_REPO_NAME=\$(git remote -v 2> /dev/null | grep \"origin.\*fetch\" | awk '{print \$2}' | sed 's,https://github.com/\(.\*\)/\(.\*\),\1,g'); export GIT_BRANCH=\$(git branch 2> /dev/null | grep \"^*\" | awk '{print \$2}')"
```

And here's what I do in `~/.emacs.d/init.el`:

```
;;; Rest of init.el code
(setq-default
  frame-title-format
  (concat 
   "%f"
   (if (getenv "GIT_BRANCH")
       (concat " in [ " (getenv "GIT_BRANCH") "/" (getenv "GIT_REPO_NAME") " ]"))))

;;; All the other goodies in init.el
```

This is all wonderful, but unfortunately, this is not always accurate, because the frame title is set by the `env` command which last evaluated my `PROMPT_COMMAND` in the `pwd` when emacs was started. If, in the same session of emacs, I open a buffer in another directory which belongs to another repo/branch, for example, my frame title is incorrect.

So my question is, any way I can make emacs re-run the git commands in shell for getting the source/repo name of the directory the buffer is located in so that different buffers will show the correct git branch/repo name?

Consider the following directory structure:

```
   gitRepoA (branch X)
   |-> buffer1.txt
   |-> buffer2.txt
   gitRepoB (branch Y)
   |-> buffer1.txt
   |-> buffer2.txt
```

Let us say I start up emacs for the file `buffer1.txt` in (the directory) `gitRepoA`. Then I see a frame title `buffer1.txt in branch X in repo gitRepoA`

If I open `buffer2.txt` of `gitRepoB` (currently checked out `branch Y`) in the same emacs session, I would like to see `buffer2.txt in branch Y in repo gitRepoB`. Currently, of course, it would say `buffer2.txt in branch X in repo gitRepoA`. Totally wrong.

If we are able to solve this problem, I'd like to solve the more general problem of re-evaluating already opened buffer's status after a `git status`-level change (say a commit, or a checkout etc.).

Any help/insight deeply appreciated. Also, a more suitable title for my question is appreciated--I am having trouble articulating my question in one title. Thanks.

Comment: the export commands can be re-written as `export GIT_REPO_NAME=$(git remote -v 2> /dev/null | awk '/origin/&&/fetch/&&/https/{split($2,a,"/");print a[4]}') ; 
export GIT_BRANCH=$(git branch 2> /dev/null  | awk '/^\*/{print \$2}') `

Comment: Rather than using `frame-title-format`, how about something like `(set-frame-name "hello-world")` to set each frame exactly as you desire?  Once the frame title is set using `set-frame-name`, it stays that way until you specifically change it -- opening a buffer will not alter the frame name.  You can change it as needed with a new `set-frame-name`.

Comment: Drew has some nice frame utility functions you may be interested in to get the frame name, go to a specific frame, and so forth:  http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/frame-fns.el  You may also be interested in this thread that intercepts files and decides which frame the buffer should be opened in:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346785/how-to-intercept-a-file-before-it-opens-and-decide-which-frame

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete example of setting frame-title, currently it works only for `git` repos

```
(defun my-get-frame-title ()
  "If inside a git repo return a string containing git repo, branch and file state else
return default frame title"
  (let* ((file (buffer-file-name))
         (git-directory (when file
                          (locate-dominating-file (file-truename default-directory) ".git"))))
    (if git-directory
        (concat (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))  
                " on " (vc-working-revision file) 
                " in " (file-name-nondirectory (directory-file-name git-directory))
                " current state is " (symbol-name (vc-state file)))
      (concat invocation-name "@" system-name))))

(setq-default
  frame-title-format
  '(:eval (my-get-frame-title)))
```

This set the frame title in `git` repos in the format `<filename> on <branch> in <repo> current state is <state>` otherwise it falls back to emacs' default frame title

Comment: I think your last line should be `...eval (my-get-frame-title)...` When I did make the change, I got both filename correctly, but branch and repo name are blanks.

Comment: You are right actually I changed the function name and forgot to update the `frame-title-format`. I am not sure why it is not working for you. Are you sure you are working on a file in `git` repo. Do `M-:  (my-get-frame-title) RET`, what do you get?

Comment: All I get is "emacs@hostname" when I do the eval after adding the code into init.el.