# How do I get the length of a file being opened in emacs init file?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

Basically, I have a `which-function-mode` that crashes on large files. Is it possible to only set it if the file is less than 1,000 lines?

Comment: Are you asking how to set it conditionally when you open up a buffer, or are you asking if you can turn it on/off dynamically as you add to/subtract from the buffer?

Comment: Actually, nevermind: the docstring for `which-function-mode` says it can only be enabled/disabled globally.

Comment: I think you may want to look at `find-file-noselect` -- you can do your test **before** the buffer is displayed.  Here is a complex example where a custom function performs certain tests on the file-name / buffer-name and then decides which window / frame to display it in (creating the frame if necessary):  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18371427/2112489

Comment: The difficulty, though, is that `which-function-mode` is not buffer-local, but global -- you could do the test, but would be disabling it globally for all buffers when you open up that large file.

Comment: @Dan That's fine but how do I actually get the length of the file?

Comment: `buffer-size` will tell you the number of characters in a buffer.  `(line-number-at-pos (point-max))` will tell you how many lines are in the buffer.  Your test could look something like `(when (< (line-number-at-pos (point-max)) 1000) (do-your-stuff-here))`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I just noticed that I had forgotten that what you want is already provided by which-function-mode.  Just customize `which-func-maxout`.

You can try something like the following:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook
          (lambda ()
            (if (> (buffer-size) 100000) ;; More than 100K characters.
                (set (make-local-variable 'which-func-mode) nil))))
```

`which-function-mode` is a global minor mode, but each buffer can enable/disable it individually by setting `which-func-mode`.  Sadly, I think the above will fail because which-function-mode doesn't expect other code to set `which-func-mode` so its own `find-file-hook` will override your setting.

This said, 1000 lines is not large, so there's no excuse for which-function-mode failing on such files: you might want to `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Neat!  Nayefc: if 1000 lines really is the limit for some reason, you could `(setq which-func-maxout (* 1000 50))` which presumes an average of 50 characters per line.  That's 10% of the default maximum of 500,000.

Comment: @Stefan: It does not fail but the file will take a long time to load up (about 30 seconds).

@Dan: setting which-func-maxout emacs freezes initially for a few seconds in the buffer. I have:

```(which-function-mode)               
(setq which-func-maxout (* 1000 50))
(setq which-func-unknown "n/a")```

Why is that? It seems to try and load it then terminate or something..?

Comment: Unless the file is really unusually large, 30s of extra scanning time is excessive.  Please `M-x report-emacs-bug` giving all the details you can (for starters, the major mode).  Another thing: better do the `setq`s before activating the mode.