# Default Emacs Window-Buffer Pairings Upon Startup

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24

What is the idiomatic elisp way to have emacs start with N buffers, M windows, and M of those N buffers loaded into windows of a designated placement and size? Or maybe there's a nice plugin for this? Specifically, I want to have an emacs session like this upon startup:

[image]

In case version matters, I'm looking to use gnu emacs 24.3.

Comment: Are you going from terminal (or a file manager such as Finder.app in OSX), such that you want to open a file in a specific window?  If so, which window do you want the file to appear in?  Or, are you just launching the GUI version without opening a specific file?

Comment: I'm using Finder.app to open emacs.app. But emacs.app could also be started with command line options via apple's `open` command, so CLI solutions could apply.

Comment: With OSX, the function `ns-find-file` is used when launching Emacs from Finder.app by opening a file -- e.g., Command+Down-Arrow.  You can create your own function and use a `defalias` -- e.g., `(defalias 'ns-find-file 'lawlist-ns-find-file)`.  I'll check back tomorrow sometime to see if you still need a solution.  If there is a specific window you want the file displayed in, please post a comment or update your question.  In two places, I modify `ns-find-file` to point to my own `lawlist-find-file` function, which in turn uses a complex `display-buffer` function that creates certain frames.

Comment: Here is a link to the setup that I'm using, which includes an example of modifying `ns-find-file` to launch from Finder.app:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18371427/2112489

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to use an Emacs **desktop** (see the Emacs manual, node **Saving Emacs Sessions**). Position things as you want, then save your setup as a desktop. (But you will need Emacs 24.4 to have the saved desktop include frame and window configurations.)

(If you use [Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) then you can have multiple *desktop bookmarks*, and flip between them with a key.)

Otherwise, you will need to write some Elisp code to re-create your frames, windows, buffers etc. in your init file.