# how to show buffer content in real time in other window when focus is in buffer list

Tags: emacs, buffer, switching

I have 2 windows, one is the buffer list, how do I show the buffer in the buffer list in the other windows when I use n and p to naviage in the buffer list?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am unaware of a simple solution because the target frame needs to be identified as there may be more than two frames.  I suppose there could be a condition that if only two frames exist, then use the other frame.  Here is a link to a complex method of controlling which frame buffers are displayed in -- I have been using this method successfully for the past year or so:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18371427/2112489

Comment: The above-comment assumes that the original poster is using the term `frame` in the same context that seasoned Emacs users do.  If the original poster is meaning to use the term `window` as seasoned Emacs users understand the term to mean, then the question needs to please be clarified.  Examples demonstrating the difference, include, but are not limited to, the following functions:  `find-file-other-window`; `find-file-other-frame`; `switch-to-buffer-other-window`; `switch-to-buffer-other-frame`.

Comment: NOTE:  `buffer-menu-mode` has toolbar entries that includes various functions to act upon files displayed in the `*Buffer List*` buffer -- e.g., `o` -- *Select in Other Window*. For those users who prefer to have the toolbar disabled / invisible, the following keyboard and mouse shortcut combination will reveal a pop-up menu similar to the toolbar:  `C-down-mouse-3`

Comment: Good question. I like this feature of the `ranger` file manager.

Comment: Sorry, the frame should be window, I am new to emacs. I have changed it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right, the answer is simply to use `C-o` in the buffer menu. that displays the buffer of the line you are on in another window, but it does not select that buffer. That is, it does not move the input focus to that buffer's window. The buffer list retains the input focus, so you can continue to use `C-o` on different lines, to display different buffers.

If you mean an Emacs window when you say "frame", then see above. The same is true even if the buffers are on different frames, with this caveat: Some window managers, including MS Windows, change the input focus to a new frame that is created. So if, for example, you have non-`nil` `pop-up-frames` (so that a separate frame is used to display a buffer), and if the buffer you choose to display (using `C-o`) is not already shown in some other frame, then displaying it not only creates a new frame for it but also shifts the focus to that new frame. If the buffer is already visible in another frame then `C-o` simply raises that frame.

There is currently no key bound in the buffer-list display, to both (a) move the cursor down or up to the next or previous buffer line and (b) invoke the `C-o` behavior of displaying the buffer named on the target buffer line. But you could easily define such a command and bind it to a key:

```
(defun show-next (arg)
  "Show next line's buffer in another window."
  (interactive "p")
  (next-line arg)
  (Buffer-menu-switch-other-window))

(defun show-previous (arg)
  "Show previous line's buffer in another window."
  (interactive "p")
  (previous-line arg)
  (Buffer-menu-switch-other-window))

(define-key Buffer-menu-mode-map "\M-n" 'show-next)
(define-key Buffer-menu-mode-map "\M-p" 'show-previous)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my prototype for this feature in a dired buffer. It kills a buffer after it got visited.

This is a feature I like from the [ranger](http://ranger.nongnu.org/) file manager, it is handy when you explore a directory.

```
(setq show-next-current-buffer nil)

(defun show-next ()
     (interactive)
     (next-line 1)
     (dired-find-file-other-window)
     (if show-next-current-buffer (kill-buffer show-next-current-buffer))
     (setq show-next-current-buffer (current-buffer))
     (other-window 1)
     )

(defun show-previous ()
     (interactive)
     (previous-line 1)
     (dired-find-file-other-window)
     (if show-next-current-buffer (kill-buffer show-next-current-buffer))
     (setq show-next-current-buffer (current-buffer))
     (other-window 1)
     )

(define-key dired-mode-map "n" 'show-next)
(define-key dired-mode-map "p" 'show-previous)
```

**edit**: I've written a minor mode to enable/disable this feature easily. See https://gitlab.com/emacs-stuff/my-elisp/blob/master/dired-show.el and meld it to your needs.

Comment: This is very useful in dired mode.